# HTML: object output error

Tags: html

I have this game that I made just yesterday, but for some reason, when you get too high of a number for your money or dollars per second, it just comes up as [object Object] dps or something.

Is there any way I can fix this?

```
<td class="money">${{money}}</td>
<td class="rate">{{rate}} dps</td>
```

That's the leaderboard output.

```
You ({{user.username}}) have ${{user.money}} and make ${{user.rate}} per second!
```

That's the output to show how much money and dollars per second you have.

The 'user rate' function:

```
  buy: function(amount) {
    if(Meteor.user().money >= amount && amount > 0) 
      Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId}, {$inc: {'rate': (Math.floor(amount/500)),  'money': (0-amount)}}); 
  },
})
```

I'm using Meteor and Notepad++.

The game is coded in Javascript, I'm just having trouble with the output when you get either 1. Too much money or 2. Too much Dollars per Second.

I don't know what you mean by 'environment info'.

Comment: That's not JavaScript. It looks like some template engine. If you've found the code in Google, it should come with instructions on how to install the appropriate library.

Comment: Just seen your edit. HTML is a mark-up language, not a programming language. It's impossible to get error messages from HTML, no matter how badly formed it is. I insist: wherever you've found that code, check for further instructions.

Comment: Maybe I should give you my javascript?
The page is written in HTML, but the game is written in Javascript.

Comment: Is this not AngularJS? But yes.. show your JavaScript.

Comment: "Give you my JavaScript" sounds like dumping your complete game here. No, please, don't. You can (and should) post the shortest code fragment that illustrates the issue. And you should care using the appropriate question tags, unless you honestly don't even know what programming technologies you are using.

Comment: What does `console.log(Math.floor(amount/500))` reveal when rate is show correctly and when it's an object? (We're still waiting for tools and env info, you are not programming in HTML.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Max safe integer for javascript is 9007199254740991, i'm assuming you are not hitting that limit!

Add some Number type checks to your code, it sounds like you're suddenly adding strings or some other type of object to his score. eg:

```
if (!Number.isInteger(Meteor.user().money) || !Number.isInteger(value)) {
   alert('found the problem!');
}
```

Don't use type coersion comparison, that will make "5" == 5, which you don't want when doing calculus.

Use if (typeof a === typeof b && a > b), because there is no "type-safe" comparison for >, <, <=, >=

Hope these pointers will send you in the right direction.